# How do I stop Gmail from sending meeting acceptance emails?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

When I select 'Yes' for going it automatically sends a response.  Often I don't want that to go because I'm simply forwarding an email from work to my gmail account so I can keep one calendar on my gmail/android.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better using a Sync tool to keep one calander. Look at http://memotoo.com